# Handle Flexible In-AppUpdate in Jetpack Compose application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, in-app-update

I have a BaseActivity which extends `ComponentActivity` and has abstract method `SetComposable`. Each Activity now extend `BaseActivity` and overrides `SetComposable` which shows Composable screen. `InAppUpdates` is integrated in application of type `Flexible` for updating application. Once user has downloaded the update, the requirement is to show `Snackbar` on Composable screen which can be any screen as user has flexibility to keep using app when update is downloading. How to handle this condition as placing `Snackbar` inside each composable is not a good option but it needs to be shown when update is downloaded.
The code for `BaseActivity` is

```
abstract class BaseActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var appUpdate: AppUpdate

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        appUpdate.setUpdateType(AppUpdateTypes.IMMEDIATE)
        appUpdate.launchImmediateUpdate(this)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {               
                SetComposable()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the composable content for the screen
     */
    @Composable
    abstract fun SetComposable()
}.
```

The code for other Activities look like

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
    class HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var navController: NavController
    
        @Composable
        override fun SetComposable() {
    }
}.
```

How to solve this use case ?